# Why is $a\sin^2(t) = \frac{a}{2} - \cos(2t)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $\sin^2(t)=\frac{1−cos2x}{2}$, but I fail to understand what happens with $a$.

Comment: Probably just a typo. There should be an $a/2$ in front of the cosine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:

$$\sin^2(t) = \frac{1−\cos(2t)}{2},$$

then:

$$a\sin^2(t) = \frac{a}{2}\left(1 - \cos(2t)\right).$$